# What are the possible cause of "__rtc_set_alarm: err=-22" error message in dmesg?

Tags: time, dmesg, clock

What are the possible cause of  "__rtc_set_alarm: err=-22" error message in dmesg?  I am seeing this in my log files but I do not try to set the alarm or schedule it anywhere.